# JMeter, request rate with loop controller

Tags: java, networking, jmeter

I have this situation:

- LoopCount

  - BeanShell prepocessor (calcualte some parameters to pass to java request object)
  - Java Requests

With this setup the rate reached is 1 req/sec. 
Is it possible, maintaining this structure, to increase the rate of requests? 
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Yes if you can run multiple threads (using a thread group). If not probably no as it seems the requests take about 1 second to complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 constraints which limit the "rate":

1. JMeter must be able to send requests fast enough
2. Application must be able to respond fast enough

---

So I'd suggest taking the following steps:

1. First of all try [switching from Beanshell PreProcessor to JSR223 PreProcessor with Groovy as the language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because [Beanshell interpreter might be the bottleneck](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).
2. Try increasing the number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) because if you have only 1 thread and cumulative elapsed time of the PreProcesor and Java Requests is 1 second you won't be able to run the requests faster
3. If you're limited with your machine resources - try running your test in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
4. If after applying the above suggestions you're still stuck at 1 request per second rate - most probably it's the system you're testing limitation

Comment: If I set a thread lifetime in a threadgroup, does JMeter try to play all n samplers (set in the loop count of the loop controller) before the time runs out? If yes, maybe Jmeter himself sets the optimal rate

Comment: Nope, it just acts as a trigger for stopping the test, the samplers will run as  fast as they can for the specified number of loops or while the time remains